# How to include high number of sub entities?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm playing with EF7 and just wondering if there is faster way how to include all the sub entities in the entity.

The classes I have:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
    public virtual C B { get; set; }
}

 public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual BA BA { get; set; }
    public virtual BB BB { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public virtual CA CA { get; set; }
    public virtual CB CB { get; set; }
    public virtual CC CC { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I do it at the moment, to include all  of the sub entities.

```
A test = _dbContext.As.Where(a => a.Id == id)
         .Include(a => a.B)
             .ThenInclude(b => b.BA)
         .Include(a => a.B)
             .ThenInclude(b => b.BB)
         .Include(a => a.C) 
             .ThenInclude(c => c.CA)
         .Include(a => a.C) 
             .ThenInclude(c => c.CB)
         .Include(a => a.C) 
             .ThenInclude(c => c.CC)
```

This is fine with a small hierarchy, but if the entities are huge there will be lots of repetition.

I don't want to turn off lazy loading.

This is how I pass query to the front end:

```
[Route("api/Test/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public A Get(int id)
    {
        A test = _dbContext.As.Where(a => a.Id == id)
         .Include(a => a.B)
             .ThenInclude(b => b.BA)
         .Include(a => a.B)
             .ThenInclude(b => b.BB)
         .Include(a => a.C) 
             .ThenInclude(c => c.CA)
         .Include(a => a.C) 
             .ThenInclude(c => c.CB)
         .Include(a => a.C) 
             .ThenInclude(c => c.CC)

        return test;
    }
```

This is what I have in `Startup.cs` under `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Comment: wait, if you are using lazy-loading you don't have to include all entities; they will be automatically included when accessed.

Comment: not if I want to send them to the front end of the web.

Comment: this is not true, the problem is that you are not iterating the properties... you have to iterate the properties (usually converting all you need in another class, or anonymous object). Provide the code that send the query to the front-end, and I'll show you how to do this

Comment: Thanks Fabio, question edited

Comment: @Fabio Luz, relying on lazy loading can impact performance, as every access to property which is not yet loaded, results in additional query to  DB. The queryable object returned from the action method will be enumerated during response serialization, and all properties of the returned entities will be accessed by the serializer, resulting in numerous queries to the DB, significantly slowing down the response (known as SELECT N+1 issue). In this case, Include should be preferred over lazy loading, because only one "big" query with JOIN's will be executed on the DB.

Comment: @felix-b I agree with you, but the OP does not want to manually "include" the properties

Comment: Actually I want to use include, what I don't want to do is repeat parent entity every time I want access child entity. Look at example .Include(a => a.C) is repeated 3 times

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `AViewModel` to represent the data you are sending to the view, and then modify your method as follows:

```
[Route("api/Test/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public A Get(int id)
{
    List<AViewModel> test = _dbContext.As.Where(a => a.Id == id)
    .Select(i => new AViewModel
      {
         a = B.BA,
         b = B.BB,
         c = C.CA,
         d = C.CB,
         e = C.CE
      }).ToList();

    return test;
}
```

Doing this you don't have to include all the properties, they will be automatically included at serialization time. However, as @felix-b said, this will impact performance, because it will generate several queries to DB. It is better to using include instead of lazy-loading.